# check if letters can be used to build word

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a dictionary like so: `{'a': 3, 'e': 1, 'p': 2, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 1}`
This means that one has 3 times an 'a', one time  a 'e' etc.

I have to check if the letters can be used to build a word, like so:

```
for letter in dict:
    for count in range(0,dict.get(letter)):
       if not (letter in word):
          return False
```

However, there is a problem here. In the case of  a word with multiple letters, it will always return true for the letters in the word, because it doesn't check for **2,3,4 etc** letters.

How do I pass this code for the word zazzing if the dict only has 'z':1 ?

Comment: Have you considered counting the letters in the word? And isn't your logic backwards? All letters in the word being in the dictionary is not the same as all letters in the dictionary being in the word. Also, don't name your dictionary `dict`, as it shadows the built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> available_letters = Counter({'a':1,'i':2,'g':3,'n':1,'z':1,'e':3})
>>> for word in ('zazzing', 'grunt', 'zig', 'egg'):
...     if Counter(word) - available_letters:
...          print word, 'cannot be made with the letters'
...     else:
...          print word, 'can be made with the letters'
...
zazzing cannot be made with the letters
grunt cannot be made with the letters
zig can be made with the letters
egg can be made with the letters
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Counter` from [collections](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html).

```
>>> c = Counter('zazzing')
>>> d = {'a':1,'i':2,'g':3,'n':1,'z':1,'e':3}
>>> c
Counter({'z': 3, 'a': 1, 'i': 1, 'g': 1, 'n': 1})
>>> for i in c.items():
...   if d[i[0]]<i[1]:
...      print "problem with ",i[0]
...
problem with  z
```

And with an 'ok' word:

```
>>> c = Counter('aigeginee')
>>> for i in c.items():
...   if d[i[0]]<i[1]:
...      print "problem with ",i[0]
...
```

So instead of `print` you can `return False` and `return True` at the end of the for loop.

---

You can also simply use the `substract` method of `Counter` (in Python ≥3.2), or the `-` operation:

```
>>> Counter('zazzing') - Counter(d)
Counter({'z': 2})
>>> Counter('aigeginee') - Counter(d)
Counter()
```

Comment: By the way, if you only want to check for equality, `if d==c:` would have sufficed. Also, you would have to use  `!=` instead of `<` as a comparison operator, I think.

Comment: What I understand is that OP rather want `c is included in d`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that may be. OP didn't say that no letters may remain left over. Good point.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is certainly right, but i found the answer of steven a bit more explaining and better looking code, so I went for his solution. Nevertheless I upvoted you.